Accessing nested property on stdClass with string representation
Is there any better option to access to node via string in PHP 8.x?
I use:
$JSONElement = 'productData->price_current->price_in_pln';
eval('$response = $json->' . $JSONElement . ';');

But actually I'm not proud of it and I don't like it.

use explode() to split the string on -> characters, then loop over it to access the properties dynamically.

OK, I so will stay with "eval" :)
